# Jenkins console shows permission denied error when command : terraform init runs in pipeline

Tags: azure, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, terraform-provider-azure

Please find below pipeline script and jenkins console output which is framed after running the jenkins job.Below shared is pipeline code jenkins and jenkins console output:

```
pipeline {
    agent any   
    parameters {
        string(name: 'myvmname', defaultValue: 'az-k8s', description: 'VM name')      
        string(name: 'mymodulename', defaultValue: 'aks', description: 'Module name') 
        string(name: 'operation', defaultValue: 'apply', description: 'terraform operation apply/destroy')
        booleanParam(name: 'AKS', defaultValue: true, description: 'AKS Cluster Creation')
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('IAC AKS -Git Clone') {
        when
        {
            expression {params.AKS==true}
        }         
        steps {
                git branch: 'main', credentialsId: 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx', url: 'http://xxx.xx.xx.x/root/rapidopsiacaks.git'
              }
        }
        stage('AKS Cluster Creation') {
        when
        {
            expression {params.AKS==true}
        }   
            steps {
                    sh '''echo "AKS cluster creation"
                    mkdir -p /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/VM_Prov_Terraform/${myvmname}
                    cp -r /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TerraformAKS/* /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/VM_Prov_Terraform/${myvmname}
                    
                      cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/VM_Prov_Terraform/${myvmname}/${mymodulename}
                      terraform init
                      terraform plan 
                      terraform ${operation}  -auto-approve
                    '''
              }
        }
    }
}
```

WHen i am running the job / triggering the job via jenkins i am getting below error (sharing complete output of console):

```
+ cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/VM_Prov_Terraform/az-k8s/aks
+ terraform init
[31mThere are some problems with the configuration, described below.

The Terraform configuration must be valid before initialization so that
Terraform can determine which modules and providers need to be installed.[0m[0m
[31m
[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mReserved argument name in module block[0m

[0m  on main.tf line 24, in module "aks":
  24:   [4mdepends_on[0m          = [azurerm_resource_group.rg]
[0m
The name "depends_on" is reserved for use in a future version of Terraform.
[0m[0m
[31m
[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mInvalid version constraint[0m

[0m  on provider.tf line 3, in terraform:
   3:     azurerm = [4m{[0m
[0m   4: [4m      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"[0m
[0m   5: [4m      version = "~> 2.65"[0m
[0m   6: [4m    }[0m
[0m
A string value is required for azurerm.
[0m[0m
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

-------------------------------xoxoxo -------------------------------

```
Also , when i run ( terraform init command ) in terminal getting below error :

[devopsadmin@jenkins1 aks]$ terraform init
Initializing modules...
╷
│ Error: Failed to update module manifest
│
│ Unable to write the module manifest file: open .terraform/modules/modules.json: permission denied

Please help !

Thanks in advance !
```

Comment: Pleas add your pipeline declaration to your question !!! Please add the relevant parts of your build's Console Output to your question !!! We're all volunteers here. The professional mind readers all have shows in Las Vegas. Thanks in advance !!! (And, BTW, one exclamation mark is sufficient – or even none at all.)

Comment: can you try deleting .terraform/modules directory and run terraform init again

Comment: Hi Gerald , thanks for your comments ...i have attached pipeline in jenkins

Comment: Hi RamaraoAdapa , tried deleting the same but still facing same issue

Comment: What version is your terraform?

Comment: Hi Chris , terraform version is : Terraform v1.0.11
on linux_amd64